# Iterating through test/train datasets

Tags: predictive-models, cross-validation

I am building a predictive model.  I split 2/3 of the data into a training set, and the rest into the test set. I build a model based on the training set.  I use the the model to test on the training set, and the test set.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to iterating through all 3 combinations of test/train datasets with my data to get more results on how well my model performs on the data?  Is there any reason to just test the model on this one partitioning of the data into test/train sets?

Answer (score 2):

Very roughly speaking, the reason to iterate through all data combinations is to more reliably estimate the generalization performance of your predictive model. The obvious drawback is, of course, a higher computational cost.

The procedure you described is often referred to as **cross validation**. Here are [two very nice articles](https://twitter.com/chengweiwei/status/354968360917798912) about it. Much more details related to your question can be found there.